# Webpack dev server does not recognize watchContentBase as valid option

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Webpack dev server does not recognize watchContentBase as a valid option. Is `watchContentBase` deprecated? If so what is the alternative? Below is the configuration of my Webpack dev server:

```js
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 8080,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    watchContentBase: true,
}
```

When I run my server, I get the following error.

> Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an
> options object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - options has an unknown property 'watchContentBase'. These properties are valid:    object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?,
>   compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?,
>   http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?,
>   onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?,
>   open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, static?,
>   watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }

Answer (score 11):

In the newer version, `contentBase` has been replaced with `static`

```js
devServer:{
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    port: 8080,
    open: true,
    hot: true
}
```

Comment: ** I have  configuration in my react app  as below**
`devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        watchContentBase: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: false,
        open: true,
    },`

I am getting error  ** watchContentBase is unknown property**  while  starting app using **npm run serve** .

I have  also modified adding  **static**  key value also but still  not resolved. 

I am using  
 "webpack": "^5.20.1",
 "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0".

Comment: npm run dev is the way to go

Comment: How do you get the older version since I don't want to use the new version, I'm following a tutorial and have no idea what I'm doing. I'm using vuejs.

Comment: I am migrating to webpack-dev-server v4.15, I got the error,
"options has an unknown property 'watchOptions" when I check the official migration doc (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md), it's mentioned this option has been moved inside "Static" property. Could you please help me to understand which property is representing watchOptions from available static property.
I currently have: watchOptions: { ignored: ignoredFiles(paths.appSrc) }

Answer (score 6):

Just rename `contentBase`  to `static`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using webpack-dev-server, [watch is enabled by default](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/).

That being said, you can remove `watchContentBase: true`, just like Kamran shows above.

```js
devServer: {
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    port: 8080,
    open: true,
    hot: true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

contentBase/contentBasePublicPath/serveIndex/watchContentBase/watchOptions/staticOptions options were moved to static option in webpack-dev-server@4.0.0. and they are no longer available.

For more details please read the migration guide at https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md